# Getting a SAS token for blob storage container doing an ARM deployment with Linked Templates

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

What I'm trying to do is deploying an ARM template using the Azure CLI on my local system, because I want to try out my changes local first, before pushing it to the repository.

We're using Linked Templates, which means I have to specify a URL where the linked templates are located and a SAS token in order to get access to these files.

The script I'm trying to execute looks like the following

```
az group deployment create --resource-group myResourceGroupName `
            --template-file azuredeploy.json `
            --parameters azuredeploy.d.parameters.json `
            --parameters local.parameters.json
```

The `azuredeploy.json` file contains the main template with the references to the other, linked, templates.
The `azuredeploy.d.parameters.json` file contains all of the regular environment parameters (like pricing tier, etc.).
The `local.parameters.json` contains 2 parameters called `deploymentContainerSasToken` and `deploymentContainerUri` (the SAS token and the location of the linked templates).

What I'm doing to create the SAS token is the following.

```
$end=date -u -d "30 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ'
$start=date '+%Y-%m-%dT00:00Z'

az storage container generate-sas `
            --account-name "mydeploymentfiles" `
            --account-key "[thePrimaryKey]" `
            --name "the/subfolder/buildversion.1+52/templates" `
            --start $start `
            --expiry $end `
            --permissions lr `
            --output tsv
```

This outputs a nice SAS token I can use.

> st=2019-11-18T00%3A00Z&se=2019-11-18T14%3A30Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=aZn3cx%2BNCnN2YhXD9%2AeTJa6TQL/pUIpbsbP4HKtFN/4%3D

When running the deployment via Azure CLI I get the message the linked templates (`the/subfolder/buildversion.1+52/templates/function-app.json`, `the/subfolder/buildversion.1+52/templates/storage.json`) can't be reached.

So I've tried downloading them from the browser, with the generated SAS token and got the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly
        including the signature.
        RequestId:2c0412dc-201e-0038-6b97-9e01ef000000
        Time:2019-11-19T05:11:12.2088927Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Mon, 18 Nov 2019 00:00:00 GMT] -
        Expiry [Mon, 18 Nov 2019 14:30:00 GMT] - Current [Tue, 19 Nov 2019 05:11:12 GMT]</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

I *think* this has something to do because I'm creating a SAS token for the container the files are in, but with the `List` and `Read` permission I should have access to it, right?

The release pipeline is working fine, I'm using the Azure Blob file copy over there in order to set the appropriate parameters.

[image: Release pipeline steps]

I'm a bit lost at this point.

What is the proper way to get a working SAS token to use for linked templates when running from the local system, where the linked templates reside in some sub-container.

Comment: Seems the sas token has expired ?

Comment: Could you please provide the structure of your container? Is that your container has some sub directories?

Comment: @Stanley: The token can't be expired (or shouldn't), because I've also tried it with 1/1/2020 and also renew the token rather frequently.

Comment: @Jim: The url I'm trying to contact is: `https://myStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/artifacts/someSubfolder/0.1.0-branch-name.1+52/templates/function-app.json?st=2019-11-18T00%3A00Z&se=2019-11-18T14%3A30Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=aZn3cx%2BYCmN2MhXA9%2BnTJa6TQL/pMIpbsbD4HPtFN/4%3R`. So the folder structure is `/artifacts/someSubfolder/0.1.0-branch-name.1+52/templates/`

Comment: I also tried changing the `+` to a `%2B` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information you provide, you want to generate SAS token for a folder in Azure Blob storage container. It is impossible. Because Azure blob storage does not have the 'Folder' concept. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata) and the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction#blob-storage-resources).
[image]

So please generate SAS token for the container which contains blobs you need to access or for every blob you want to access. For example

```
#generate sas token for container
az storage container generate-sas `
            --account-name "<you account name>" `
            --account-key "<your account key>" `
            --name "<your container name>" `
            --start $start `
            --expiry $end `
            --permissions lr `
            --output tsv
# generate sas token for one blob
az storage container generate-sas `
            --account-name "<you account name>" `
            --account-key "<your account key>" `
            --name "<your Blob name>" `
            --container-name "<your container name>" `
            --start $start `
            --expiry $end `
            --permissions r `
            --output tsv
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! The steps in Azure DevOps should have made this clear also, as the fields are called `Container` and `Blob Prefix`.